# I am accessing MySQL table in PHP but it is not executing if condition and directly display the table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

The code below is accessing the database table directly, but I want it to display the table content on giving conditions in drop down menu like when I select islamabad in one drop down menu and lahore in other as given in code and press search button, then it display the table flights, but it is displaying it directly

```
<p class="h2">Quick Search</p>

    <div class="sb2_opts">
     <p>
   </p>
<form method="post" action="haseeb.php">
 <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
<p>
    From:</p>
<select name="from">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<p>
    To:</p>
   <select name="To">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
</form> </table>

<?php

$from =  isset($_POST['from'])?$_POST['from']:'';
 $to = isset($_POST['to'])?$_POST['to']:'';

 if( $from =='Islamabad'){
     if($to == 'Lahore'){



$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';

$database = 'homedb';
$table = 'flights';

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user))
    die("Can't connect to database");

if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
}
}







mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `<select name="To">` and `$_POST['to']`: `$_POST`-indices are case-sensitive.
This should not be the issue since `$to` becomes an empty string because it is not set but it might cause a problem.

Comment: its still not working just showing the table directly @Birk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the mysql_ and mysqli_.
Do not repeat the SQL Query to test $result. One is ok.
Fix the case of index - to or To.

Table displayed directly: Hope you are not refreshing the form with the pre-submitted values of your cities. Freshly open the page link, and confirm that $from, $to are really empty. If you are pressing F5 in browser, it may be wrong.

Comment: thanks one more thing i want to know that how to initialize and use another mysql table in code?? @bimal poudel

Comment: You should pass $link in each mysql_query. $link is the output of a new mysql_connect()'s return. You can use multiple $links. By default, only the last generated $link will be used. Check further at: http://php.net/mysql_connect